# Ionic push notification for ios using FCM

Tags: firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

I am trying to send push notification on my iOS device with the help of FCM and ionic 3. But I'm unable to get on my device, for android it is working fine, but for iOS its not working. I'm getting device token for iOS and I've enabled push notification from xcode also. 
Is there any other configuration, which I'm missing between iOS and FCM?

Comment: for iOS , you need to have Push Notification Certificate from the Developer Console and add it to the thirdparty site

Comment: @Webruster I've already created Push Notification certificate from developer console. I've added .plist file into my root folder of project. Is there any other configuration ?

Comment: if you are creating  Certificate then you need to have XCODE 8 so that there you need to enable push notification, in order to avoid all these trouble give a try of OneSignal

Comment: @Webruster Setup is working for Android. facing problem for iOS. We have uploaded all the certificates and enabled push notification in Xcode8. How to find out errors in FCM.

Comment: @Webruster I'm getting {"error":"InvalidRegistration"} message from server.

Comment: So basically you are making an error in sending the DeviceID received by the phone to the server. Make sure your code does not alter the deviceId in any way. You have not posted the code for accepting the Id's.

Comment: @Webruster I'm using push plugin for device token and I think device token is correct. Please let me know which code you want to see.        
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=12341234 --save

Comment: const pushObject: PushObject = push.init(options);

      pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

      pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
        console.log('Device registered', registration);
        self.deviceToken = registration.registrationId;
        holders.setDeviceToken(self.deviceToken);
      });

Comment: @Webruster Thanks for your help. Now I'm able to get success message from FCM for both android and iOS. But I'm not getting notification on phone. I've checked all notification settings in phone and everything is correct. Is there any other this I've to do ? Success messege from FCM is:        {"multicast_id":6322773343649641690,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1495084051364516%1cb3b69df9fd7ecd"}]}

Comment: make sure the device which you are checking in iOS , that device is added in the pust notiication profile

Comment: @Webruster I'm using only one device for development, Each and every certificate is using that device only. By seeing success message from FCM one thing is clear that FCM is sending notification on my device token, the only thing is how to get on device. If you have any idea plz let me know. Thanks !!

Comment: @Webruster Is there any difference b/w distribution and development certificate in Apple. Because right now I'm using only development certificate. Is there any restriction for push notification in development certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Steps for ios FCM Integration:

1. Add the GoogleService-info.plist file in to the root folder of your app.
2. Add the plugin to your app following this link : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/
3. Write the necessary code
4. Run command in terminal/cmd 'ionic cordova prepare'
5. Open Xcode and allow the code to be indexed.
6. Click on 'show project navigator' on the extreme left hand side below run button. Check the Resources Folder and click on GoogleService-info.plist. If it is empty, delete it and manually place the file again in that folder by dragging and dropping.
7. Under Capabilities, ON push notifications and ON background modes> remote notifications
   8 Upload p8 file on firebase console.
   9 and you're done! Test your notification :)

Note: Don't forget to use actual device to test this feature. iOS Simulator doesn't support notifications.

App Crash Issue: Make sure that platforms/ios/MyApp/Resources/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist and platforms/ios/MyApp/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist
are same and complete. An incomplete file on any of the above paths can lead to crashing of the app.